# Java Multithreading: cheap operation to add object to List/Queue/Set

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, addition, java.util.concurrent

So basically I need a way to add an object (let's call it Element) to a List/Queue/Set or something similar with multiple threads. Since I need to add a lot of elements (not sure how many but trust me A LOT), the operation should be cheap. Removing them is not necessary. Also it's extermly important that every Element is added to the list.

Basically I'm looking for this:

- threadsafe
- cheap add function
- not comparable/not sorted
- every element needs to be added

Since **CopyOnWriteArrayList** sounds quite expensive in my case, I don't think this is an option.

Unfortunately I can't make the Element comparable so **ConcurrentSkipListSet** is not an option.

**Collections.synchronizedList()** sounds too expensive as well.

Currently I'm thinking about using a **ConcurrentLinkedQueue** or just synchronizing the add method like this:

```
private synchronized void add(Element elem){
    elements.add(elem);
}
```

Comment: Do you need only the unique elements? Can you use third party libraries? Have you done any benchmarks to compare ConcurrentLinkedQueue with CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Comment: Agree with Wow, "sounds like" is not a good argument for choosing an implementation. You need to perform measurement, not least because these cases behave differently depending on a lot of things, and you don't really go into detail.

Comment: Also, why do you think you can't make an element comparable? You can provide a wrapper class that extends Element or contains Element and implements Comparable<Element>. Also ConcurrentSkipListSet has a constructor that takes a Comparator as argument. There's also ConcurrentHashMap out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should stick to the methods and classes from the JDK library; they tend to be rather optimized, and will be down the road in future versions which will result in your code being updated without effort in your part. In fact, this is one item in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java.

Heeding that rule, and since you don't seem to really care about what kind of collection you really get ("`List`/`Queue`/`Set`" in your question), why don't you just do

```
Collection<YourData> synced = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<>());
```

`LinkedList` optimizes adding elements (as opposed to `ArrayList` which will copy the underlying array when the capacity is exhausted), and `synchronizedCollection` will do the `synchronized` wrapping (if you look into the code, it's implemented exactly as you propose). So does `synchronizedList` btw.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be too expensive. I only need the  write access (the add method) to be synchronized and not the reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can implement one Collection based on `ConcurrentHashMultiset` from [guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html).

`ConcurrentHashMultiset` is implemented based on `ConcurrentHashMap` which has done a lot of things to get solid performance.

Comment: In generally that might be an option but I don't want to use a library.